# I want to populate Cities Dropdownlist by selecting Provinces From Provinces Dropdown List by providing arrays statically in code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show the cities by selecting the province from ddlProvinces. How I can get these cities in dllCities on basis of selection from ddlProvince?

```
public partial class Countries : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            string[] Provinces = { "Punjab", "Sindh", "NWFP", "KPK" };
            ddlProvinces.DataSource = Provinces;
            ddlProvinces.DataBind();


        }
    }

    protected void ddlProvinces_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] PunjabCities = { "Lahore", "Sargodha", "Multan" };
        string[] KPKCities = { "Peshawar", "Mardan", "Sawat" };
        string[] SindhCities = { "Karachi", "Badin" };
        string[] NWFPCities = { "Quetta", "Sibi" };



    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string, string[]>` and fill it `dict.Add("Punjab", new string[] { "Lahore", "Sargodha", "Multan" });` and then when a state is selected, get the cities: `string[] citiesOfState = dict[selectedCity];`

Comment: @OguzOzgul sir this is not working is their any other way to solve it

Comment: It would work. You could not implement it probably.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
  public partial class dropDown : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    public String[] provinces;
    public String[][] cities;

    public dropDown()
    {
      provinces = new string[] { "Punjab", "KPK" };
      cities = new string[][]
      {
        new string[] { "Sargodha", "Lahore", "Faisalabad" },
        new string[] { "Peshawar", "Mardan", "Sawat" }
      };
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (IsPostBack)
        return;

      province.DataSource = this.provinces;
      province.DataBind();
      province.SelectedValue = "Punjab";

      city.DataSource = this.cities[0];
      city.DataBind();
    }

    protected void province_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      var element = (DropDownList)sender;
      var selected = element.SelectedIndex;
      city.DataSource = cities[selected];
      city.DataBind();
    }
  }
}
```